# TypeError at / 'URLResolver' object is not a mapping Django-rest-registration

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Пытаюсь прикрутить djangorestregistration в свой проект, что-то делаю не так и вылетает ошибка

stacktrace

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
March 29, 2020 - 11:09:52
Django version 3.0.4, using settings 'e_shop.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/artyomlazovikov/internet_shop/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/artyomlazovikov/internet_shop/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/debug_toolbar/middleware.py", line 99, in __call__
    bits[-2] += toolbar.render_toolbar()
  File "/home/artyomlazovikov/internet_shop/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/debug_toolbar/toolbar.py", line 69, in render_toolbar
    return render_to_string("debug_toolbar/base.html", context)
  File "/home/artyomlazovikov/internet_shop/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/home/artyomlazovikov/internet_shop/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/home/artyomlazovikov/internet_shop/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/artyomlazovikov/internet_shop/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/utils.py", line 95, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/artyomlazovikov/internet_shop/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/artyomlazovikov/internet_shop/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/artyomlazovikov/internet_shop/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 309, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/artyomlazovikov/internet_shop/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/artyomlazovikov/internet_shop/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/artyomlazovikov/internet_shop/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 443, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "/home/artyomlazovikov/internet_shop/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 55, in reverse
    app_list = resolver.app_dict[ns]
  File "/home/artyomlazovikov/internet_shop/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 521, in app_dict
    self._populate()
  File "/home/artyomlazovikov/internet_shop/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 485, in _populate
    {**defaults, **url_pattern.default_kwargs},
TypeError: 'URLResolver' object is not a mapping
```

urls

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings


apipatterns = [
path('accounts/', include('rest_registration.api.urls')),
]

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('api/', include((apipatterns, 'api'), namespace='api')),
path('', include('products.urls'),
path('api/v1/', include(apipatterns)),
)] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar
    urlpatterns = [
        path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),

    ] + urlpatterns
```

settings

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
STATICFILE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'qcfgnc+)aksmye+@7^dmkuubkgko65z@^3eszh=cl6x%&g749!'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'products',
    'users',
    'orders',
    'django_extensions',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'django_filters',
    'rest_registration',

]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'e_shop.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
        TEMPLATE_DIR
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'e_shop.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ('django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',)
}

REST_REGISTRATION = {
    'REGISTER_VERIFICATION_ENABLED': False,
    'RESET_PASSWORD_VERIFICATION_ENABLED': False,
    'REGISTER_EMAIL_VERIFICATION_ENABLED': False,
}

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

INTERNAL_IPS = [
    '127.0.0.1',
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-ru'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL ='/media/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    STATICFILE_DIR
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    path('', include('products.urls'),
    path('api/v1/', include(apipatterns)),
)]
```

Заменить на

```
    path('', include('products.urls')),
    path('api/v1/', include(apipatterns)),
]
```

Comment: Когда я делал это в прошлый раз - не работало)))